# pdflatex mysteriously loses half a line

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I have encountered a very mysterious problem. When I send my document to my professor, he found half a line of text is missing in the PDF file, meaning that it left as blank but occupies correct spaces.

I checked my .tex file, it is OK. But when I compile it again, it appears as that. If I delete some random words, it may not reproduce that error. I will try to produce a minimal W.E.

I am working with Win 7 + MiKTeX 2.9 + pdflatex

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I delete even a single comma, then error has gone!

Comment: What exactly are you using to view the PDF? DOes it also appear when it is printed? How about when you zoom in?

Comment: @daleif I use Adobe Acrobat X and SumatraPDF. It also appear when it is printed or zoom in. It seems not the problem of viewer.

Comment: what do you mean by "line"? a rule or a line of text?, what do mean by "missing"? blank space left, off the edge of the page, rest of document moved to fill space that should have the line? Your question is so unclear it's hard to even guess any possible solution.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The text is missing but occupies correct spaces. I shared my files on dropbox. Sorry that it is quite big. The error appears at the last line before Reference. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yxi1h9ftclktc2/AACqnU1xTNJvsNRwvI1g6jj4a

Comment: I see the problem in the provided PDF. But not if I recompile the sources using TeX Live 2014. Exactly which LaTeX installation are you using?

Comment: @daleif My editor is WinEdt Build: 20140613  (v. 8.2) - 32-bit. MiKTeX 2.9. I compile with pdflatex. The first line of log file is: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.6.14). "

Comment: Is it fully updated? Not just single packages, the whole thing. I have never seen LaTeX provide a PDF with things missing like that.

Comment: @daleif It is quite weird. This is also my first time saw it. Yes, I run update wizard quite often and I just did it now.

Comment: Looking at the `.log` from your DropBox, your installation seems a bit strange. Is it normal to have MikTeX files in two locations? `D:\CTEX\MiKTeX` and `D:\CTEX\MiKTeX`. Another thing to test, is to copy the files out of Dropbox into another folder on your computer and try compiling it there. Just to rule out DropBox.

Comment: @daleif a) I run the file with TeXwork by pdflatex, it cannot reproduce the problem. b) If I run biber again, then pdflatex, it cannot reproduce the problem either.

Comment: @daleif The missing text in that line is copiable out of PDF:(

Comment: Strange. The output from `pdflatex` should not be affected by the editor in question. Have you checked exactly which options WinEdt is using when it is calling `pdflatex`, they might not be the same as how `TeXworks` calls `pdflatex`

Comment: @MaMing: That dropbox link doesn't work (404).